# $AX=B$ solve for $X$ ....... in MATRIX

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$ 2x - 3y + 4z  = -19\\
6x + 4y - 2z  =8   \\
x  + 5y + 4z  =   23
$$
what I have done so far is I put the nubmer and $x, y $ and $ z$ in matrix form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -3 & 4\\
    6 & 4 &-2\\
    1 & 5 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-19\\         
8\\
23
\end{bmatrix}
$$
step 2: I don't know where to go from here

Comment: Do you know how to invert a matrix?

Comment: yes it will be x= A^-1B

Comment: I can do it on calclulator but don't know how to do row operation without calculator

Comment: That's it! Compute and you get $X$ as a vector.

Comment: Do you know how to convert an augmented matrix into echelon form?

Comment: Google is your friend http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxinvr.htm a good book on matrices even more ;-) evern wolframalpha can help you (to check your result) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=invert+%7B%7B2%2C-3%2C4%7D%2C%7B6%2C4%2C-2%7D%2C%7B1%2C5%2C4%7D%7D

Comment: once I find the inverse how do you find x then

Comment: Hint: $[A:I] \to [I:A^{-1}]$ and $Ax=b \Longleftrightarrow x = A^{-1}b$

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gaussian Elimination on the augmented coefficient matrix to solve for $x, y, z$ by expressing the matrix in *reduced row echelon form.*

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -3 & 4 &\mid&19\\
    6 & 4 &-2&\mid & 8\\
    1 & 5 & 4& \mid &23
\end{bmatrix}$$

If you do this correctly, you should obtain the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 &\mid&20/9\\
    0& 1 &0&\mid & 7/9\\
    0 & 0 & 1& \mid &38/9
\end{bmatrix}$$
 This means that $$\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 20/9 \\ 7/9\\38/9\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: `-19` tho, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule):
$$
x=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{r}\color{#C00000}{-19}&-3&4\\\color{#C00000}{8}&4&-2\\\color{#C00000}{23}&5&4\end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{r}2&-3&4\\6&4&-2\\1&5&4\end{array}\right|}=-2
$$
$$
y=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{r}2&\color{#C00000}{-19}&4\\6&\color{#C00000}{8}&-2\\1&\color{#C00000}{23}&4\end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{r}2&-3&4\\6&4&-2\\1&5&4\end{array}\right|}=5
$$
$$
z=\frac{\left|\begin{array}{r}2&-3&\color{#C00000}{-19}\\6&4&\color{#C00000}{8}\\1&5&\color{#C00000}{23}\end{array}\right|}{\left|\begin{array}{r}2&-3&4\\6&4&-2\\1&5&4\end{array}\right|}=0
$$
In the numerator, replace the column in the matrix corresponding to the given variable by the column of results. Note that the bars denote the determinant of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a system of equation in the form
$$
A\cdot x = B
$$
where A is a $3$x$3$ matrix, $x$ is your $3$ elements vector and $B$ is your constant vector. You get your $x$ doing
$$
x=A^{-1}\cdot B
$$
Since I am lazy I used the computer to solve it. Your result is
$$
20/9, 7/9, 38/9
$$